# I'm having trouble trying to read the numbers (0 - 10) into a list in Python 3 using CSV file and in a column format.

Tags: python, numbers

I first wrote the numbers in a column into a CSV file but having trouble with the reading part. I want to make into one list and make sure that the numbers are converted into ints

```
f = open('numbers.csv', 'r')
with f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for column in reader:
        print(column)
```

This is what I wrote for my code and here is my output but how do I make it into a list and convert the numbers into integers?

Column:

```
['0']
['1']
['2']
['3']
['4']
['5']
['6']
['7']
['8']
['9']
['10']
```

Comment: Have you saved your numbers in list literally, like "['0']"?

Comment: You seem to be confusing columns and rows. `reader` is a list of rows, and each row is a list of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to iterate over each `row` in your `file`, cast the first `column` to `int` using `int()` and then add to a `list`. Here is compact version:

```
with open('numbers.csv', 'r') as numbers_file:
    reader = csv.reader(numbers_file)
    int_list = [int(row[0]) for row in reader]

print int_list
```

**EDIT**:

If you want a `column` list or `nested` list, just loop over both `columns` and `rows` for the *general* case:

```
int_list = [[int(col) for col in row] for row in reader]
```

or in your *particular* case where you just want the `first/only` element of each row, just cast the `element` to a `list`:

```
int_list = [[int(row[0])] for row in reader]
```

Comment: i got the answer in a row instead of column though; I need the answer to be in column format (vertically). each number on each line

Comment: @VRam Is this more like it?

Comment: I tried the new one you said, but still not getting it in a column format. I need each number to be in each line like this: [0,
           1,
           2,
           3,
           4,
           5,
           6,
           7,
           8,
           9,
           10]    but vertically not horizontally

Comment: basically [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] in a column format. So the int_list = [[int(row[0])] for row in reader] actually worked out but not getting that in a column format

Comment: I think you might have gotten the wrong idea about `python lists`, `python lists` do not have an orientation or dimension property, they are just an `array`. Are you thinking about `numpy.arrays`?

Comment: yeah but my teacher said you can get into this format:   [0,
           1,
           2,
           3,
           4,
           5,
           6,
           7,
           8,
           9,
           10] but vertically

Comment: is there anyway using the code above to get the number in each line? Like 0 in the first line, 1 in second line, 2 in third line, so on so forth?

Comment: When you say _"each line"_, do you mean that you want to print the `list`? Or do you want to convert it to a `string`? Then there are lines. In a `python list`, there are no lines.

Comment: yeah print the list so that the each number is on each line: [0 on first line, 1 on 2nd line, 2 on third line, ...] looks like a column?

Comment: Well you have the `list` already. And there are plenty of resources out there on how to `iterate` through a list, line breaks `\n` and `printing`, I'm sure you can work it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
numlist = list()
f = open('numbers.csv', 'r')
with f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for column in reader:
        numlist.append( int(column[0]) )
print( numlist )
```